# API Json response to format of List of maps

Tags: java, json, api, rest

I am struggling a little bit to get a JSON response from the API server in a readable format.

So here is the page I am currently using for exercises:
https://reqres.in/ Position 4, GET LIST Resource

I am able to retrieve the data from the server in the JSON format which looks like:

```json
{
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "cerulean",
            "year": 2000,
            "color": "#98B2D1",
            "pantone_value": "15-4020"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "fuchsia rose",
            "year": 2001,
            "color": "#C74375",
            "pantone_value": "17-2031"
        },
```

and so on. I am able to retrieve one object in the form of String:

```
[id:1, name:cerulean, year:2000, color:#98B2D1, pantone_value:15-4020]
```

I have 6 objects like that in an array, I am looping through the JSON response using:

```java
System.out.println("Json Array count: " + count);

for (int i = 0; i<count; i++){
    String books = js.getString("data["+i+"]");
    System.out.println(books);
}
```

Is there an easy way to transcribe this data to the list of maps? I.e
K: id, V: 1 and K: name, V: cerulean etc

I am a freshman if it comes for coding.

Here is my whole class:

```java
String baseURI = RestAssured.baseURI = "https://reqres.in";

RequestSpecification rs = given().header("Content-Type","application/json");
Response response = rs.when().get("/api/unknown");

System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
response.then().statusCode(200);
Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());

String resource = response.prettyPrint();

JsonPath js = new JsonPath(resource);
int count = js.getInt("data.size()");

System.out.println("Json Array count: " + count);

for (int i = 0; i<count; i++){
    String books = js.getString("data["+i+"]");
    System.out.println(books);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use generic `get` of `JsonPath` in your case like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    String baseURI = RestAssured.baseURI = "https://reqres.in";

    RequestSpecification rs = given().header("Content-Type","application/json");
    Response response = rs.when().get("/api/unknown");
    List<Map> result = response.jsonPath().get("data");
    for(Map map: result){
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mister Alexey, thank you very much, that resolved my problem.